# Sql Query into Access database(.accdb)

Tags: sas, ms-access-2010

I'm using right now , and its working, a proc sql to connect to my DB(access .accdb). Until now I was only using it to do SELECT query. Here is a example that work and that I use to do so.

```
proc sql;
/* create an ODBC pass-through connection using the Microsoft Office Access 2007 .accdb    driver */
connect to ODBC as savesdb
    (required="driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb); dbq=&dir_BD.;");

 create table MYTABLE as select * from connection to savesdb(select MYID from ACCESSTABLE); 

/* close the pass-through connection */
disconnect from savesdb;
 quit;
```

Now I want to execute a INSERT INTO query. I know that the next code is working

```
execute( INSERT INTO ACCESSTABLE ( MYID ) VALUES ( 1 )) by savesdb;
```

The thing is in the INSERT INTO I want to specify to insert the values that are in a dataset. In other word I have a dataset with 4 records so I want to call my insert into 4 times with the values in dataset.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Are you looking for syntax like that shown in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208861(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Not exactly, my goal is to do a INSERT INTO query but the data that I want to insert is in a dataset. Here is a example : execute(INSERT INTO MYACCESSTABLE (MYFIELD1,MYFIELD2,...) SELECT * FROM WORK.MYDATASET.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to use sql pass-through? The easy road is to create a libref to the access database and use proc append to add your records to mytable.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is loop through the DataSet in a data step and read the columns to a macro variable.. one var for each column.

then call the proc sql code with these macro variables as input to the macro definition which will do the insert into DB using full pass through.

however as pointed out libref is the easier method.

Thanks,
Manish